# read or write file to filesystem with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit

I will read/write a file with angular from/to my hdd. I normaly use node module "fs". Whats the best practice to combine this module with angular to use it in node webkit?

Thanks!

Edit: (can't use require in angular to load npm modules. any ideas?)

```
.service("WindowService", WindowService);

        function WindowService() {
            this.gui = require('nw.gui');
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wrote this [example](https://github.com/jstacoder/angular-node-fs), if you had any questions as to how things are working? you may also want to check out [this](https://github.com/jstacoder/node-ng) as well, which the former example uses to work outside of the browser.

but since the main question is regarding the error involving the `require` function, i will elaborate. `require` is a function implemented by the node runtime, it was added because there was no way initially built into js to import code from fileA to fileB. so when your in the browser you dont need to require anything, just make sure you have the file added to the html ie: `<script src="my/file.js"></script>`. but if you really want to do require in the browser, just use [browserfy](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-browserify).

Comment: @kyle-roux how do you actually use this library? I get how to add it as a dependency into the app module but cannot get it into a controller. I cannot inject a module named with dot syntax into a controller...

Comment: @atwright147 i think im pretty sure i know where your going wrong, and im sure i can help explain what you need to do, im currently working on a more detailed answer to this question so everyone will have a firm example, but if you want me to explain just email me jstacoder at gmail, thanks for using node-ng, i love that people use it

Comment: @atwright147 ok, i added a little more info in the [wiki](https://github.com/jstacoder/node-ng/wiki/how-to-use) on github for node-ng, hopefully this helps a little

Answer (score 1):

I have similar experiences to you. I usually wrap modules to services and use it as normal angular service with DI.

This makes code more readable and maintanable. Also, when you want to change node module, you are changing it in one place.

Comment: Thanks! i have found following example: https://github.com/jstacoder/angular-node-fs. this looks like your code?

Comment: Yes, it looks similar, but I use JS.

Comment: I can't use require. (Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined) I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

for your project, i will look to
socket.io > [for broadcast websocket, and update your angular scope...](http://socket.io/)
shokidar > [better than FS, with less bug than fs](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)

Comment: for what i should use socket i.o? chokidar looks nice. thanks!

Comment: i use socket.io for broadcast modification in my files & tell my angular modules to update the data on all the client connected. that just in case.